# Burrows-Wheeler Move to Front

Tags: java, compression, huffman-code

For a project that I'm working on, I need to implement Burrows-Wheeler's MoveToFront transformation in O(n) space. For some reason, though, my code works on most values that I throw at it, but not all.

My implementation looks something like this:

```
public byte[] transform (byte[] input)
{
    if (input.length == 0)
         return input;
    IndexedByte[] bytes = new IndexedByte[input.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        bytes[i] = new IndexedByte(input[i],i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length -1; i++)
    {
        bytes[i].next = bytes[i+1];
    }
    bytes[input.length - 1].next = bytes[0];
    Arrays.sort(bytes);

    byte[] newBytes = new byte[input.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
        newBytes[i] = bytes[i].b;

    int[] indexes = new int[input.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++)
        indexes[i] = (bytes[i].origIndex + (input.length - 1)) % input.length;
    int x = 0;
    String str = new String(input); 
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        if (bytes[i].origIndex == 0)
        {
            x = i;
            break;
        }
    }   
            byte[] header = intToByteArray(x);
    byte[] result = new byte[indexes.length+header.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < header.length; i++)
        result[i] = header[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++)
        result[i+header.length] = input[indexes[i]];
    return result;
}
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong here? It seems that this does not work when a non-alphanumeric character is encountered (i.e. encoding itself, it seems that the /*, etc. will screw it up).

Comment: The line `String str = new String(input);` is unnecessary but unlikely to be your problem.

Comment: You might want to include the code for intToByteArray

Comment: Whoops, sorry: http://pastebin.com/d6726a4ab

Comment: It seems that this does not work when a non-alphanumeric character is encountered (i.e. encoding itself, it seems that the /*, etc. will screw it up).

Comment: intToByteArray is simply a bit shift from an int into 4 bytes

Comment: The IndexedByte.compareTo(Object) method looks a bit odd (where it delegates to comparing against the next IndexedByte). Is this some sort of optimization?

Comment: The creation of `newBytes` also seems to be unnecessary (it is not accessed once populated).

Comment: Just double-check (or show) the inToByteArray method - simple bit shifts often screw up because we deal with signed values... just my experience

Comment: private byte[] intToByteArray (final int integer) {
  byte[] byteArray = new byte[4];
  byteArray[3] = (byte) integer;
  byteArray[2] = (byte) (integer >> (8));
  byteArray[1] = (byte) (integer >> (16));
  byteArray[0] = (byte) (integer >> (24));

  return (byteArray);
 }
 public static final int byteArrayToInt(byte [] b) {
  return (b[0] << 24)
   + ((b[1] ) << 16)
   + ((b[2] ) << 8)
   + (b[3] );
 }

Comment: The compareTo has to compare against the next IndexedByte in the list in the case that there are two strings aab and aac, aab must come first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running various tests on this code it looks as though it works correctly. The problems you are seeing are probably due to sign extension in the `byteArrayToInt` implementation. For example, the following code prints `-128` rather than the expected `128`:

```
System.out.println(byteArrayToInt(intToByteArray(128)));
```

Try changing the code to:

```
private int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b) {
    return (b[0] << 24) + 
          ((b[1] & 0xFF) << 16) + 
          ((b[2] & 0xFF) << 8) +
           (b[3] & 0xFF);
}
```

As an aside the `MAXIMUM = 50000` limit within `IndexedByte.compareTo` is never reached. I got a `java.lang.StackOverflowError` with an input array of length 5214. I'd suggest changing this to be iterative rather than recursive (this should be fairly easy since you know the length of the input array and it will also prevent superfluous looping in the pathological case where all bytes in the input array are equal).